# BUILD FAILED after ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I created a Ionic project using blank template then added below Google Maps plugin:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="XXXXX"
```

Here are the versions:

```
•   Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.4
•   Ionic CLI 2.1.8
•   Cordova 6.4.0
•   Node 6.8.1
•   NPM 3.10.8
```

Then I tried "ionic build ios" and got this error:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GoogleMapsViewController.o MyApp/Plugins/plugin.google.maps/GoogleMapsViewController.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/myusername/Documents/MyApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,MyApp.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 arm64,-target,MyApp,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/myusername/Documents/MyApp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/myusername/Documents/MyApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

This process used to work out of the box few months ago and now it's completely broken

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/

Do you have any idea how to fix this or the right versions (of anything) to revert back?

Thanks.

Comment: did you tried removing iOS platform and adding it again before build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed ios platform v 3.9.0 and it worked.